# Passing a variable from an asp.net codebehind to an xsl

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt-1.0

Is it possible to pass a public variable set in an C# asp.net codebehind page through to be then used within XSL 1.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe so - this would be an example

```
 XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
 xslt.Load("order.xsl");

 // Create the XsltArgumentList.
  XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();

 // Create a parameter which represents the current date and time.
  DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
 xslArg.AddParam("date", "", d.ToString());

 // Transform the file.
 xslt.Transform("order.xml", xslArg, XmlWriter.Create("output.xml"));
```

The parameter date is replaced from within the xslt stylesheet

The XSLT fragement that is replaced looks like this

```
<date><xsl:value-of select="$date"/></date>
```

This is all from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163439%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It works from ASP.Net 2.0 onwards